# Managing sections in tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have two sections in my `tableview`.
First one for - one custom cell nib, second one - for another.

Data for both is loaded from separate arrays.

But the issue is - whether i append arrays or perform `insertRowAtIndexPaths` - rows never appear below both sections, they append the current section.

Example:

```
Section1:
Cell1: Nib1
Cell2: Nib1
Cell3: Nib1
Section2
Cell4: Nib2
```

If i append it happens this way

```
Section1:
Cell1: Nib1
Cell2: Nib1
Cell3: Nib1
Cell4: Nib1
Cell5: Nib1
Section2
Cell6: Nib2
Cell7: Nib2
```

I want it

```
Section1:
Cell1: Nib1
Cell2: Nib1
Cell3: Nib1
Section2
Cell4: Nib2
Section1:
Cell5: Nib1
Cell6: Nib1
Section2:
Cell7: Nib2
```

How do i achieve that?
Thank you.

Comment: This is confusing. You showed, you want Section1 to have 3 cells(cell1, cell2, cell3) and section2 to have 1 cell(cell4). Then again, you wanted, section1 to have 2 cells(cell5, cell6) and section2 to have 1 cell(cell7). You can not have section 1, 2 and then 1, 2 again. You supposed to have section 1,2,3,4 something like that. Please clarify

Comment: @natasha yes, that's right. I want them in cyclic order.

Comment: You can't. I don't know why you need such a scenario but I don't think, you can. Think about it this way- the section number is it's identifier. so you can't have two sections with same identifier. You may want to explain why you need such a scenario so that others can think of any other way.

Comment: It's rather simple. I have several lines of questions in the first cells with nib1 and a reply uibutton in the second nib. Once the uibutton is pressed underneath the loaded cells - another set of nib1 cells is appended along with the nib2 reply cell. Sorry for not explaining myself thoroughly in the beginning.

Comment: Okay, I understand now and for that you may not need a cyclic order, but just to be clear before I provide you with a solution, can you attach a screen shot of your initial tableview(before clicking the button in cell4).

Comment: Sure. This is how the initial tableview looks after launching the build http://imgur.com/d6Ofh3O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88204/discussion-between-david-robertson-and-natasha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method check what current selected section is and append rows on it. U can check current section with `indexPath[section]`